# A 2nd grade verbal classification about dish and casserole

Tags: meaning

I am stumped by this question that my daughter asked me.  This is a verbal classification question, in case it is not clear.

> Determine why the first 3 words are similar, then select the word from the available answers that is most similar to the first three words.
>
> First three words: platter, bowl, plate
>
> Available answers: dish, spoon, casserole, tongs, oven

Both my daughter and I chose "dish", but the correct answer is "casserole". Can somebody help explain why?

Comment: You're using 'the correct answer' where 'answer claimed [by the people setting this test] to be the single correct one' is more accurate.

Comment: The meanings of all of these terms is highly variable, and "casserole" is especially variable, in US usage.  This test is simply stoopid.

Comment: Why "casserole" is more accurate than dish?

Comment: Is there anywhere in the Anglosphere that refers to a casserole dish as just a "casserole"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's yet another question about a bogus English test.

Comment: It can only be "dish". A "casserole" is used for cooking food in, whereas the other items are mainly used for serving food on.

Comment: http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchen/broccoli-and-orzo-casserole-3361875?syc=applenews_foodnetwork-5-hearty-casseroles-ready-to-warm-you-up--comfort-food-feast.  Here *casserole* means the food.  *casserole dish* is the “dish” it’s baked in.

Answer (score 1):

'Find the similar word' questions like this are imprecise and subjective. It is often possible to make good arguments for several words in a list.

Like you I would have chosen dish. Platter, bowl, and plate are all things you put food on and then eat off. Dish fits that pattern. Casserole is generally a vessel for cooking, (though it is also a kind of food) and none of the three words are. However there may be a similarity I haven't seen. Maybe they are all derived from Latin words.

Assuming this question was set to your daughter, I would ask the person who set the question what the reason is. And then I would forget the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Platters, bowls, and plates are all *types* of dishes, so "dish" doesn't fit the pattern, since nothing can be a subset of itself. The only thing in your list that remotely qualifies as a type of dish is a casserole, which takes pride of place among the platters, bowls, and plates in all its cream of mushroom goodness. Perhaps the connection between "dish" and "casserole" is more immediate if you're from Minnesota, where a casserole as food is called a "hot dish."  [image]

Comment: A *casserole* is something you cook and serve in a *dish*.

Comment: I. Would very much question your statement that a plate is a kind of dish.

Comment: A casserole is a dish you can serve in a casserole, just as green bean casserole is a dish you can serve on a dish. I am more interested in the cultural knowlege sich a question presupposes. How many second graders can identify so many kinds of tableware?

Comment: So DJ, If you "do the dishes," do you leave the plates on the table for the cat to lick clean? In this case, "dishes" includes glass- and silverware.

Comment: Definitions for “dish” are all over the place. Google’s definition lists platter, bowl and plate as synonyms. This would make “dish” the right answer. Personally, to me, only the plural “the dishes” works as a general term, but this also includes silverware and glassware. And no one would argue that a fork is a “dish”.  Also, I don’t see a casserole as a “dish”, unless they mean “dish” as in a specific prepared recipe. The container is, to me, a casserole pan more than dish, and is not very dish-like to me.

Comment: "do the dishes" is a construct where the specifics (dishes) stand in for the general (cooking and eating utensils). It doesn't make glasses or silverware a kind of dish. Nobody says "hand me a dish" and expects a knife.

Comment: I believe the white ceramic casserole illustrated above satisfies all salient characteristics of "dishness." It is neither food nor a pan, and as Azor-Ahai pointed out, most call it a casserole dish. If you asked someone to draw a dish, you'd probably get a plate, unless the person were thinking of a dish of ice cream, then you'd get a bowl. A clever soul, however, might ask you what kind of dish — candy dish, tapas dish, asparagus plate... "Dish" is plenty generic. By elimination, "casserole" is the only possible answer as the question is posed. I was attempting to reverse engineer the logic.

Comment: I think that if this many adults find so much fault with the question, then it's safe to say that it was poorly constructed for second graders, whose concept of dishness would likely be far less advanced than those who have posted here.

Comment: @KarlG - Yeah, you really need to get into the 7th or 8th grade before boys appreciate the meaning of "dish".

Comment: This is from the Verbal part in CogAT test for 2nd grade. Among all the answers and comments, I think the logic behind is about what this answer pointed out, it refers to type of dish (as hardware instead of food). However my last question is that "casserole" is food for sure but does it also refer to the container of the food? As a few comments above seem to indicate that "casserole" is a type of food and its container is "casserole dish" or "casserole pan".

Comment: @DonaldWang  - It depends entirely on what your mother called it.

Comment: 'Casserole' can refer to either a kind of food (originally a French regional dish, but more generally any stew-like dish) or the kind of oven-ready cooking pot the dish is cooked in(and which the original French dish was named after).

Comment: @Hot Licks, unfortunately my mom never cooked or used casserole in China though she was a English professor there. I learnt this word from my daughter pretty  much because she asked me this question:(

Comment: @Donald Wang: Again, welcome to cultural bias.